# How to change the icon theme in Unity 8?

Tags: icons, themes, unity-tweak-tool, icon-themes, unity8

17.04 has just been released, and with it a usable version of Unity 8. I would like to change the icon theme (and the overall theme if possible) from default ubuntu to paper. The unity tweak tool affects unity 7 only.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: have you checked out the `dcont-editor` tool?

Comment: @Anwar not yet. I will check it right now.

Comment: @Anwar the icon theme is already set to "Paper" in dconf editor but the icons are default ubuntu.

Comment: I need a few inputs from you. Can you join [this room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57147/anwars-halpfile-d)?